# Lock fps of the ARKit

Tags: swift, arkit

I want to take an snapshot from `ARKit` view (`ARSCNView`) 30 times per sec, and since the CPU usage is so important in my case, I try to not use `Timer` or `displaylink` and instead run the taking image function inside `session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)` .
But it normally run in 60 fps and then come to 30 fps after a while.
So I try to lock it on 30 fps

```
sceneView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30
```

But looks like it's not working and it is still doing it in 60 fps. Is there any way to lock it on 30 fps all the time ( 30 ps or lower ). If not, there is any way that we can find out its fps in the first 1-2 sec to modify the taking image function base on it ( run in every frame in 30 fps or run in every 2 frame in 60 fps)

Thank you so much

Comment: in snapshot taking function you can check elapsed time since last snapshot and if it is >= 1/30 second, then do take capture, otherwise ignore

Comment: can you show me an example? Thank you so much

Comment: in pseudo code (as I don't know swift): `current = gettimems(); if (current - previous < 1/30 second) return; previous = current; // take snapshot`